# Simple present tense rule: adding s to verb form he, she or it

Tags: present-simple

In Longman's advanced grammar book the rule says 'The form of the present simple verb only changes after he, she or it, when we add -s to the base form (-es after o, s, sh, ch and x; -ies when the base form ends in -y)

In an example : *A colony of Antarctic penguins **lives** in Marwell Zoo.*

My understanding : add 's' only if he, she or it is present

My question: is 'A colony of Antarctic penguins' considered as 'it'? Or am i missing something else?

Comment: The rule is badly stated: replace *after he, she or it* with *after a third-person singular subject*.

Comment: @StoneyB got it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, "*A colony of Antarctic penguins*" is considered as "*it*". Indeed, the subject of this sentence is "*A colony*". The penguins just represent the composition of the colony. You could replace the sentence by "***A colony lives in the city.***" Therefore, the subject is singular and at the 3rd person. You have to use the -s rule.

So you would write:

> **A colony of Arctic penguins lives in the city.**

Or if the penguins were the subject, you would write:

> **Some Arctic penguins live in the city.**

Comment: +1 Cause **a colony** is singular, meaning **it** and **pinguins** is plural, meaning **they**.

Comment: @SovereignSun *because*, not *cause* :)

Comment: @SovereignSun The word "pinguins" don't exist. The plural is either "Pinguine" in German or "pinguinen" in Luxembourgish.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie An easy mistake to make, considering that the bird is _пингвин_ in Russian ("pingvin").

Comment: @alephzero I've almost never used this word in Englush, yeh penguins is correct.